# Issue Getting New Variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

This is my first ever post, so bear with me. I am trying to manipulate a data set in R by adding new columns based on existing data. I've converted my data to a data frame and have employed the mutate function. The function works. However, when I call my dataset again to look at the changes, the new column disappears. What am I doing wrong?

```
# Converting raw data into a tibble data frame for easier data analysis:
spdata <- as_tibble(rawdata)

# Creating a new Grade column based on Math Scores
spdata %>%
    mutate(math.grade = case_when(math.score < 60 ~ "F",
                                  math.score >= 60 & math.score <= 69 ~ "D",
                                  math.score >= 70 & math.score <= 79 ~ "C",
                                  math.score >= 80 & math.score <= 89 ~ "B",
                                  math.score >= 90 & math.score <= 100 ~ "A"))
```

Here is the output that automatically generates after I run my mutate function:

```
# A tibble: 1,000 x 9
   gender race.ethnicity parental.level.of.education lunch        test.preparation.course math.score reading.score writing.score math.grade
   <fct>  <fct>          <fct>                       <fct>        <fct>                        <int>         <int>         <int> <chr>     
 1 female group B        bachelor's degree           standard     none                            72            72            74 C         
 2 female group C        some college                standard     completed                       69            90            88 D         
 3 female group B        master's degree             standard     none                            90            95            93 A         
 4 male   group A        associate's degree          free/reduced none                            47            57            44 F         
 5 male   group C        some college                standard     none                            76            78            75 C         
 6 female group B        associate's degree          standard     none                            71            83            78 C         
 7 female group B        some college                standard     completed                       88            95            92 B         
 8 male   group B        some college                free/reduced none                            40            43            39 F         
 9 male   group D        high school                 free/reduced completed                       64            64            67 D         
10 female group B        high school                 free/reduced none                            38            60            50 F         
# ... with 990 more rows
```

My new math.grade variable shows up as expected.

However, when I call spdata again to look at it, the math.grade column is missing:

```
# A tibble: 1,000 x 8
   gender race.ethnicity parental.level.of.education lunch        test.preparation.course math.score reading.score writing.score
   <fct>  <fct>          <fct>                       <fct>        <fct>                        <int>         <int>         <int>
 1 female group B        bachelor's degree           standard     none                            72            72            74
 2 female group C        some college                standard     completed                       69            90            88
 3 female group B        master's degree             standard     none                            90            95            93
 4 male   group A        associate's degree          free/reduced none                            47            57            44
 5 male   group C        some college                standard     none                            76            78            75
 6 female group B        associate's degree          standard     none                            71            83            78
 7 female group B        some college                standard     completed                       88            95            92
 8 male   group B        some college                free/reduced none                            40            43            39
 9 male   group D        high school                 free/reduced completed                       64            64            67
10 female group B        high school                 free/reduced none                            38            60            50
# ... with 990 more rows
```

Comment: "dplyr functions never modify their inputs, so if you want to save the result, you’ll need to use the assignment operator, <-."  https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html    In your case, this would look like `spdata <- spdata %>%.... [the rest]`

Comment: Can use `magrittr` `tee`(well it's named pipe too) (`magrittr::`%<>%`) for inplace assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the data frame with the additional column to a new variable with `<-` :

```
new_df <- spdata %>%
    mutate(math.grade = case_when(math.score < 60 ~ "F",
                                  math.score >= 60 & math.score <= 69 ~ "D",
                                  math.score >= 70 & math.score <= 79 ~ "C",
                                  math.score >= 80 & math.score <= 89 ~ "B",
                                  math.score >= 90 & math.score <= 100 ~ "A"))
new_df
```

This should work...

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I'm super new and I'm trying to teach myself.